# How to pass value to another php using ajax..?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Since i'm new to ajax and dont know much about it... ive created 2 php files one is 
**six.php** and another is **six-cuf.php**...**Based on user inputs in six.php and clicks submit this will call the six-cuf.php using ajax and do the calculation.**

**But, when i executed and monitored the code thru network tab in chrome i came to know that the values were being passed to six-cuf.php , but it was not going inside the if condition inside the page hence it was not getting any response.**

**Its not entering inside if() at the begining in the above code in six-cuf.php what is the mistake**

**when i used json_decode it returned null so use json_last_erro and it returned following error msg....Syntax error, malformed JSON**

**Six.php**

```
       <body>
   <div class="six">
    <form onsubmit="callphp()">
    <label>CUF PERFORMANCE</label>
    <select id="select" name="options">
    <option>Select The Value</option>
    <option id="hourly" value="a">Hourly</option>
    <option id="daily" value="b">Daily</option>
    <option id="monthly" value="c">Monthly</option>
    <option id="yearly" value="d">Yearly</option> 
   </select><br/><br/>

    <label id="from"  style="display:none;">Enter starting Date and Time</label>
    <label id="start"  style="display:none;">Enter Starting Date</label>
   <input id="dateInputone" name="dateipone" type="datetime-local" step="600" onblur="validate_time(this.value)" style="display:none;" >
   <input id="dateIpone" name="dateone" type="date" style="display:none;">

   <label id="to"  style="display:none;">Enter Ending Date and Time</label>
   <label id="end"  style="display:none;">Enter Ending Date</label>
   <input id="dateInputtwo" name="dateiptwo" type="datetime-local" step="600" style="display:none;">
   <input id="dateIptwo" name="datetwo" type="date" style="display:none;" >
<br/><br/>

<label for="Inverter">Inverter</label>
<select name="ino" id="ino">
<option>Select The Value</option>
<option value="1">Inverter 1</option>
<option value="2">Inverter 2 </option>
<option value="3">Inverter 3</option>
<option value="4">Inverter 4</option> 
<option value="5">Inverter 5</option> 
<option value="6">Inverter 6</option>
 </select><br/>


 <input type="submit"  value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="myFunction()">
<br><br>
</div>

<script>
     function callphp(){
     var dataa = {};
     dataa.dateipone = jQuery("#dateInputone").val();
     dataa.dateiptwo = jQuery("#dateInputtwo").val();
     dataa.ino = jQuery("#ino").val();
     dataa.options = jQuery("#select").val();
     dataa.dateone = jQuery("#dateIpone").val();
     dataa.datetwo = jQuery("#dateIptwo").val();
     dataa.submit = "submit";

$.ajax({
    url : "six-cuf.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data : JSON.stringify(dataa),
    contentType : "application/json",
    success:function(data)
    {
        if(data){ 
          alert(data);   
          //console.log("Data from Server"+JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        else{
          console.log("Data is empty");
        } 
     },
     error: function(xhr) {
        alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status + " Message = " + xhr.statusText);
        //console.log('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status + " Message = " +  xhr.statusText);
    }
});
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**below is six-cuf.php**

```
     include 'db.php';  
     if(isset($_POST["dateipone"],$_POST["dateiptwo"],$_POST["ino"],
    $_POST["options"],$_POST["dateone"],$_POST["datetwo"],$_POST["submit"]))
    {   
      $format = $_POST["options"];

      if($format == 'a')
      {   
       date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
       $fromdate = $_POST["dateipone"];
       $start =new Datetime('@'.strtotime( $fromdate));
       $todate = $_POST["dateiptwo"];
       $end =  new Datetime('@'.strtotime( $todate));
       $inverter = $_POST["ino"];
       $count = 1;
$query = "SELECT timestamp, gridpowertotal FROM inverterlog where inverter = '" . $inverter . "' AND timestamp BETWEEN '" . $fromdate . "' AND '" . $todate . "'";

if ($result = mysqli_prepare($con, $query))
{
   mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $timestamp, $gridpowertotal);
   $arr1= array();
   $arr2=array();
   $array_associate = array();
   $hourArray = array();

   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result))
   {
         $obj =  new stdClass();
         $obj->timestamp = $timestamp;
         $obj->gridpowertotal = $gridpowertotal;
         $array_associate[$timestamp]=$obj;
   }

    mysqli_stmt_close($result);
    mysqli_close($con);

    $interval = new DateInterval('PT10M');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval ,$end);
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($daterange as $date){
        $index = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        if($count%6 == 1) {
            $backupIndex = $index;
        }
        if($count%6==0) {
            $count++;
            if(array_key_exists($index,$array_associate) && $array_associate[$index]!=null){ 
                $sum = $sum+$array_associate[$index]->gridpowertotal;
            } 
            else {
                $sum = $sum+0;
                $obj2 =  new stdClass();
                $obj2->timestamp = $index;
                $obj2->gridpowertotal = 0;
               $array_associate[$index] = $obj2; 
            }
            $obj1 = new stdClass();
            $obj1->timestamp = $backupIndex;
            $obj1->sum  = $sum;
            array_push($hourArray,$obj1);
            $sum = 0;
        } else {
            if(array_key_exists($index,$array_associate) && $array_associate[$index]!=null) {
                $sum = $sum+$array_associate[$index]->gridpowertotal;
            } else {
                $sum = $sum+0;
                $obj2 =  new stdClass();
                $obj2->timestamp = $index;
                $obj2->gridpowertotal = 0;
               $array_associate[$index] = $obj2; 

            }
            $count++;
        }

    } 
    var_dump($hourArray);
    $narray = array_values($hourArray);

       foreach($narray as $object){
         array_push($arr1,$object->timestamp);
         array_push($arr2,$object->sum); 
       }
    }
     header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('format'=>"Helllo"));  
 }
  else 
   if($format == 'b')
   {
     $fromdate = $_POST['dateone'];
     $todate = $_POST['datetwo'];
     $inverter = $_POST['ino'];
     $dayArray = array();
     $arr1 = array();
     $arr2 = array();
     $query = "SELECT DATE(`timestamp`) as timestamp, SUM(`gridpowertotal`) as gridpowertotal FROM inverterlog where inverter = '" . $inverter . "' AND DATE(`timestamp`) BETWEEN '" . $fromdate . "' AND '" . $todate . "' GROUP BY  DATE(`timestamp`)";
if ($result = mysqli_prepare($con, $query))
{
   mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $timestamp, $gridpowertotal);
   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result))
   {
       array_push($dayArray,$timestamp,$gridpowertotal);
       array_push($arr1,$timestamp);
      array_push($arr2,$gridpowertotal);    
   }
    var_dump($nArray)."<br/>";
    var_dump($arr1)."<br/>";
    var_dump($arr2)."<br/>";       
  }

mysqli_stmt_close($result);
mysqli_close($con); 
}

else
 if($format == 'c')
 {


 }

 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: You have to decode JSON from `POST` into Array in your PHP code. And you are not sending data properly. Read more about Ajax.

Comment: This is not how you should have your files organized. Based on what you've shown. `Six.php` should just be a regular .html file (`six.html`) and when the user submits, the data is sent to `six-cuf.php`. .php files are for performing server operations. The first file doesn't need that.

Comment: @Oen44...an just give me an example to decode with respect to my code...just one sample...i dont know much about ajax...pls..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've used json, you need to decode the parameters by using `json_decode` on the *six-cuf.php*. Here take a look at the  [php's tutorial for json_decode](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: ...can just give me an example to decode with respect to my code...just one sample...i dont know much about ajax...pls..??

Comment: I'm not that much into json and I recommend you to put datas manually. i.e = data: { 'dataipone' : document.getElementById("dateInputOne").value } etc. But the json format should look like this; var_dump(json_decode($_POST['dataa'])); This should give you an array of the elements you have stringified in ajax. If it doesn't work, it'd be because of the post name. I'm not 100% about it.

Comment: ....when i tried to decode json it returned null ..so I used json_last_error and it returned the following error message Syntax error, malformed JSON..any solutions..??

Comment: Okay, try to change the ajax data section as this; 
data: { 'dataa' : JSON.stringify(dataa) } 
and get the post as $_POST['dataa'] on the php page

Comment: @ Ümit Aparı..no not working buddy...tried as u metioned in above comment..

Comment: As I told you, I don't know too much about JSON's. The one way It might work is to enter the post data manually. i.e :  data: { 'dateipone' : document.getElementById("dateInputOne").value, 'dateiptwo' : document.getElementById("dateInputTwo").value } etc. etc. Then you can read the post data's on php page as $_POST['dateipone'], $_POST['dateiptwo']

Answer (score 0):

You said you have a problem with you first statement - you are right.

```
if(isset($_POST["dateipone"],$_POST["dateiptwo"],$_POST["ino"], $_POST["options"],$_POST["dateone"],$_POST["datetwo"],$_POST["submit"]))
```

You need to check if the variable is set for each variable.

Change that to this:

```
if(isset($_POST["dateipone"]) && isset($_POST["dateiptwo"]) && isset($_POST["ino"]) && isset($_POST["options"]) && isset($_POST["dateone"]) && isset($_POST["datetwo"]) && isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

Comment: @Pradeep Then just remove the isset check for the empty variable in the if statement.

Comment: @Edward..when i tried to decode json it returned null ..so I used json_last_error and it returned the following error message              
Syntax error, malformed JSON..any solutions...